Why didn't Steve Zahn receive a credit for Silo?
I was watching S2E3 "Solo" of the show Silo and there is a character named Solo in a locked room talking through a view hole. I recognized the voice and eyes but was trying to place him and so I pulled up the credits on various sites and could not see the character listed anywhere. The episode credits also do not list the character and actor. This is especially strange considering the episode title is named after the character. I finally placed him in my mind as Steve Zahn who is a pretty significant name to leave out of the credits. Why was he left off the credits?

At the request of the actor, apparently.

In fact, Solo is so full of secrets that star Zahn actually wanted to have the character be a complete surprise for viewers, pitching to Apple that they don't reveal his casting or anything in the build-up to season 2's release. As Zahn told GamesRadar+: "I actually wanted to and pitched to Apple that they shouldn't give me any credit or even announce me until I actually appear in like episode 3. Yeah, that would have been kind of cool, but then we wouldn't be talking right now!"
One Silo season 2 actor wanted Apple to hold back details about his mysterious newcomer until after the show had aired: "That would have been kind of cool"


For the record, his involvement was heavily trailed, so his appearance was zero surprise to anyone.

Seems an odd choice to go against his suggestion as far as announcing and trailing goes, but then go with it by leaving him out of the credits… if they’re going to trail him so everyone already knows it’s him, why leave him out of the credits when he actually does appear (even he himself only says, “until I appear in like episode 3”)?

@JanusBahsJacquet - He seems to want credit (and adulation) for not being credited.
